# Adding new user in Linux

Tags: linux, users

I created a new user in Linux using

```
useradd connectweb
```

and I see the following in the /etc/passwd file

```
connectweb:x:1002:1002::/home/connectweb:/bin/sh
```

but when I try to navigate to the folder /home/connectweb, the folder does not exist../home is available but /home/connectweb is not available.

Comment: [This](http://askubuntu.com/questions/152707/how-to-make-user-home-folder-after-account-creation) might be helpful.

Answer (score 4):

Just follow the command below to resolve your case

1. execute this command to add directory

   ```
   mkdir -p /home/connectweb
   ```
2. in case of need copy files from `/etc/skel` directory to have `.bashrc`
   and so on files
3. change ownership of this directory

   ```
   chown -R connectweb:connectweb /home/connectweb
   ```
4. if you want to increase a little bit the security change the
   permissions

   ```
   chmod 700 /home/connectweb
   ```

In the future you can use the `-m` option to `useradd` to do the above for you.

Comment: Don't forget to `chmod 700 /home/connectweb`.

Comment: @orion, good point, will add it :)

Answer (score 3):

As with all commands, read the man page if they show a undesired behavior.

Here `man useradd` says:

```
   -m, --create-home
       Create the user's home directory if it does not exist. The files and
       directories contained in the skeleton directory (which can be defined with
       the -k option) will be copied to the home directory.

       By default, if this option is not specified and CREATE_HOME is not enabled,
       no home directories are created.
```

Either remove the user again and recreate him with the `-m` option or create the home directory manually.

Answer (score 0):

I think the OP is concerned about why did not the `useradd` command create the home directory.

The `CREATE_HOME` directive in the `/etc/login.defs` file decides whether the `useradd` command should create the home directory by default (without having to use the `-m` option) or not. If it is commented out or set to `NO`, only then you will have to explicity use the `-m` option for the `useradd` command to create the home directory.

```
[root@server ~]# grep CREATE /etc/login.defs
CREATE_HOME    yes
[root@server ~]#
```

If `CREATE_HOME` is set to `yes`, then the `useradd` command will create the home directory in the path mentioned in the `/etc/default/useradd` file.